# How to read a text file to a variable in batch and pass it as a parameter to a powershell script

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I have a powershell script that generates a report, and I have connected it to an io.filesystemwatcher. I am trying to improve the error handling capability. I already have the report generation function (which only takes in a filepath) within a try-catch loop that basically kills word, excel and powerpoint and tries again if it fails. This seems to work well but I want to embed in that another try-catch loop that will restart the computer and generate the report after reboot if it fails a second consecutive time.

I decided to try and modify the registry after reading this article: https://cmatskas.com/configure-a-runonce-task-on-windows/

my plan would be, within the second try-catch loop I will create a textfile called RecoveredPath.txt with the file path being its only contents, and then add something like:

```
Set-ItemProperty "HKLMU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce" -Name '!RecoverReport' -Value "C:\...EmergencyRecovery.bat"
```

Before rebooting. Within the batch file I have:

```
set /p RecoveredDir=<RecoveredPath.txt
powershell.exe -File C:\...Report.ps1 %RecoveredDir%
```

When I try to run the batch script, it doesn't yield any errors but doesn't seem to do anything. I tried adding in an echo statement and it is storing the value of the text file as a variable but doesn't seem to be passing it to powershell correctly. I also tried adding -Path %RecoveredDir% but that yielded an error (the param in report.ps1 is named $Path).

What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: The batchfile is in Desktop, along with recoverdpath.txt

Answer (score 1):

One potential problem is that not enclosing `%RecoveredDir%` in `"..."` would break with paths containing spaces and other special chars.

However, the bigger problem is that **using *mere file name* `RecoveredPath.txt` means that the file is looked for in *whatever the current directory happens to be***.

In a comment your state that both the batch file and input file `RecoveredPath.txt` are located in your desktop folder.

However, it is not the *batch file's* location that matters, it's the *process' current directory* - and that is most likely *not* your desktop when your batch file auto-runs on startup.

Given that the batch file and the input file are in the *same* folder and that **you can refer to a batch file's full folder path with `%~dp0`** (which includes a trailing `\`), modify your batch file to look as follows:

```
set /p RecoveredDir=<"%~dp0RecoveredPath.txt"
powershell.exe -File C:\...Report.ps1 "%RecoveredDir%"
```